# How to trigger a vba macro for a shared mailbox in MS Outlook when new mail arrives

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have created a new 'rule' inside outlook that searches for a specific word inside the mail subject when a new mail is received. If it finds the specific word , it then calls the script below. The script was created as a new module under the default Project1.

The script strips the attachment out the email and places it on the local computer. It works perfectly for my personal inbox, but I'm struggling to get it working for a group inbox.

The group inbox name I believe is called "Mailbox - ! XXXX XXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXX". I retrieved this from right clicking on the shared inbox and looking under 'general' tab under the Location: field.

I'm thinking that I need to add in the group inbox name somewhere in my code and then reference the MailItem in that, as I'm guessing it is looking in my personal inbox for the MailItem. Just not quite sure on how to add it. :(. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "d:\temp\"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Application_NewMail is not working for this?

Answer (score 0):

Too late to change the Inbox if using a rule.

Add the shared mailbox to your profile and try ItemAdd. http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62.

The sample code goes in the ThisOutlookSession module.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  ' instantiate objects declared WithEvents
  Set olInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  On Error Resume Next
  Itm.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
  Itm.Save
  Set Itm = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can point to the shared Inbox with something like this.

```
Set olInboxItems = _
  objNS.Folders("Mailbox - ! XXXX XXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXX").Folders("Inbox").Items
```

Comment: thanks, could you have a go at answering my question. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513822/in-vba-outlook-how-do-i-write-an-if-statement-that-searches-for-a-specific-wo

Comment: getting a permission error saying 'cannot save attachment - do not have permission to do so'. Any ideas?

Comment: Edit the question. Add your current code to the original question.