# How do I write an IF statement that searches for a specific word in an email's subject line

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I've got a rule + script setup in outlook. The rule looks for specific words in the email subject and then runs the script (defined in Modules) below. But it seems to be only working for my personal inbox and not a group inbox. The below is the code that works.

*The lines in comments are me trying to work it out.*

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "d:\temp\"

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

'Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'Set myRecipient = objNS.CreateRecipient("XXXXXXX")
'myRecipient.Resolve
'set Items = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox).Items
'Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem

' If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
'    Set itm = item

     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use rule + run script.

Comment: I've got a rule + script. but Its only working for personal mailbox and not group inbox, maybe I should change the question

Comment: @Om3r I recommend pretending Run a script does not exist.

Comment: @Niton why ? Run + Script seems like a good suggestion

Comment: Run a script will breaks rules for unknown reasons. If you have that experience you can put the rule conditions in ItemAdd code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to go and read the email subject to launch further code :

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, _
    oNS As Outlook.NameSpace, _
    oFld As Outlook.Folder, _
    oMails As Outlook.Items, _
    oMail As Outlook.MailItem, _
    oAtt As Outlook.Attachment, _
    SaveFolder As String

SaveFolder = "d:\temp\"

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set oNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFld = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oMails = oFld.Items

For Each oMail In oMails
    If InStr(1, oMail.Subject, "Txt_to_Find") Then
        '----Your code comes here
        For Each oAtt In oMail.Attachments
            oAtt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & "\" & oAtt.DisplayName
            Set oAtt = Nothing
        Next oAtt
    Else
    End If
Next oMail
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @R3uk for this. Also looking to expand your code a bit. I've posted the details in another question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534706/in-vba-outlook-how-to-compare-text-from-the-subject-line-against-current-date)