# Compare text from the subject line against current date - 1

Tags: vba, outlook

I've a list of mails that come in every few days with the subject as:

- CUSTOMER ORDERS1-04/11/2015
- CUSTOMER ORDERS2-04/11/2015
- CUSTOMER ORDERS3-04/11/2015
- CUSTOMER ORDERS1-03/11/2015
- CUSTOMER ORDERS2-03/11/2015
- CUSTOMER ORDERS3-03/11/2015

I want to do something only when subject is CUSTOMER ORDERS1 and 04/11/2015 = todays date - 1.

I'm thinking I would need to

- extract textual date from the subject, then convert it to date format as DD/MM/YYYY Then compare that date against the current -1 in that format.
- Also I would need to extract CUSTOMER ORDERS1 from subject and also compare it against "CUSTOMER ORDERS1".

Below is the code

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, _
    oNS As Outlook.NameSpace, _
    oFld As Outlook.Folder, _
    oMails As Outlook.Items, _
    oMail As Outlook.MailItem, _
    oAtt As Outlook.Attachment, _
    SaveFolder As String, _
    Yesterday as String

SaveFolder = "d:\temp\"
Yesterday = Format(Now()-1, "mm.dd.yy")

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set oNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFld = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oMails = oFld.Items

For Each oMail In oMails

    If InStr(1, oMail.Subject, yesterday) 
            and InStr(1, oMail.Subject, 'CUSTOMER ORDERS1')  Then
        '----Your code comes here
        For Each oAtt In oMail.Attachments
            oAtt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & "\" & oAtt.DisplayName
            Set oAtt = Nothing
        Next oAtt
    Else
    End If
Next oMail
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried to extract the date and other values from the subject line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the entire comparison by replacing `"Txt_to_Find"` with `"CUSTOMER ORDERS1-" & format(date-1,"dd/mm/yyyy")`

But if you are looking for the entire text string, then `instr` is inefficient, you would be better just doing `oMail.Subject = "CUSTOMER ORDERS1-" & format(date-1,"dd/mm/yyyy")`

Just a note on usage though, `instr` returns the position of a string within another string, rather than a simple true/false of whether it exists, so you need to do `instr() > 0` to get `TRUE` if the string does exist.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just tried the "Txt_to_Find" with "CUSTOMER ORDERS1-" & format(date-1,"dd/mm/yyyy"). Working nicely. Haven't tried the other one. Would it just be .... If (oMail.Subject = "CUSTOMER ORDERS1-" & format(date-1,"dd/mm/yyyy") then ?